# Problem with booting (computer boots weirdly)

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2

I've downloaded and burned the .iso file from Ubuntu page (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS), and burned it on USB with Rufus.

Now, I've already had Ubuntu installed, but because of this problem, I thought I'd reinstall it directly by Ubuntu instructions, since I didn't for the first time.

I've also reset the CMOS settings to default, I thought maybe something I've done on the PC while messing with themes and installing lots of stuff via terminal may've messed up with BIOS.

Now, I went through this procedure when installing:

1. Try Ubuntu (I didn't install immediately, but through try mode)
2. Install Ubuntu
3. Download updates and third party apps
4. Erase disk and install Ubuntu

And then all the other misc stuff (date, place, login info etc).
I also set it to log me in automatically (no password).

When I rebooted the PC, I normally booted it from the HDD. But the thing is, the boot is super weird. It takes about 50 sec to boot.

This is how it goes:

1. Purple screen
2. Screen power saving mode
3. Black screen with something written in the top left corner (/dev/sda1 something, I also noticed the word "clean")
4. Ubuntu load screen
5. Black screen (I think)
6. Instant load of desktop (w/o animations, desktop just shows up)

I don't think this is how it's supposed to boot, is it?

What do you think about the issue? And how should I fix it?

*edit* - SPECS

Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 250, 3.00 GHz
RAM: 2x 4gb DDR3
Motherboard: MSI 770-C45 (MS-7599)
GC: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 220] (rev a2)

*edit*2 - BOOT TIMES

10.971s apparmor.service
6.207s ModemManager.service
5.117s accounts-daemon.service
4.990s dev-sda1.device
4.982s snapd.firstboot.service
3.130s networking.service
3.035s systemd-logind.service
2.809s console-setup.service
2.779s NetworkManager.service
2.727s pppd-dns.service
2.469s avahi-daemon.service
2.186s gpu-manager.service
2.091s polkitd.service
1.873s lightdm.service
1.784s apport.service
1.530s grub-common.service
1.476s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
1.417s plymouth-start.service
1.326s systemd-journal-flush.service
1.132s plymouth-quit-wait.service
1.128s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
1.103s colord.service
1.061s systemd-journald.service

Comment: Give us an estimate on boot time.  The black screens can happen to appear on switching graphics mode, which is not uncommen. If you want more help attach the printout of `dmesg -H` to your question. Yet I believe everything went just fine.

Comment: Sorry.  I think the whole time is around 20 sec.

*edit* I was wrong, I checked with a stopwatch and it's 50 sec

Comment: If older laptop with slower HDD, that may be normal. But if newer system may be slow. What video card/chip? If nVidia or AMD you may need a driver.

Comment: It's a desktop, and it's indeed old (7y). But before I installed Ubuntu, I had windows, which was yesterday, and it booted to login screen in ~15 sec or less. Now, after I installed Ubuntu, it's 50 sec.

Answer (score 1):

The black screens are due to changes in resolution and often times also created by changing graphics drivers.

Plus as you choose on installation your system logs in automatically, hence no login screen.

Seems everything is fine.

Comment: When I had Windows (yesterday), it booted to login screen in 10 sec. No way skipping login screen takes ~40 sec.

Comment: Windows does tricks to bring up the screen faster than completing the boot. If you want to get to know, what takes the most time booting run `systemd-analyze blame` and add it to your question.

Comment: Well, this totals to 67 sec. Can I setup to skip some of these? I don't know what are they yet though

Comment: I guess there is not much to do, probably you can kick out `plymouth`, `avahi`, `snapd` and `apparmor`. yet each has its perfect reasoning for it's existence. lets keep it going here

Comment: Meh. What do you think this would look like if I had a 2x2.5GHz processor?

Comment: most likely not worse, because on a certain point harddrive has  bigger effects, yet we can try to get things lower, but this would become a different/new question.

Comment: Well I meant if it would be faster. Essentially the boot doesn't matter that much to me, but Ubuntu feels certainly different than windows, and I just don't want it to crash/work slowly for unknown to me reasons.

Comment: yeah i wouldn't delete anything either  to be honest. to make your  graphical environment a bit more responsive you can try the procedure described at the end of this article https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/09/19/low-graphics-mode-in-unity-7/ - installing nvidia-graphix-driver should not have any big effects, but you can go for it with `ubuntu-drivers list` and `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: hi any progress on this issue?

Comment: yeah man, everything works fine! i don't even remember what i did anymore, i think i just booted with win7 live cd and then reinstalled ubuntu